# sdiff usage regaring merging changes in to an output file? How to come out of edit mode?

Tags: diff, ed, sdiff

I tried
`sdiff file1 file2 -o file3` and everything seems to be going well.
I could enter `l` or `r` to choose left or right side content in to the output file.

But for a particular change, I had to edit the left side content and then save it to output file.
So I entered `el` and it went in to edit mode and allowed me to type text. But I am now not able to come out of the edit mode. It's giving `?` at the beginning of line, but I am not sure how to get out of the edit mode. I tried `vi` options like `!q`, `!x`, etc. but to no rescue.

**Can someone guide on how to come out of sdiff edit mode?**

Answer (score 2):

The edit mode, which you entered with [`el`](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Merge-Commands.html#Merge-Commands), uses [`ed`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ed.html), the standard editor.
The latter prints a `?` as answer to an unexpected command (you can
reply with `h` to see what is the hindrance). To quit, choose one:

- `q` if no changes were made.
- `w` and `q` to save changes and quit.
- `Q` to force a quit (losing changes if any, recommended if you did not know what you were doing).

If none of those work, you have probably entered insert mode with `i`, `c` or `a`,
which you exit with `.` or `CTRL-C`. Then try again one of the three items above.